# Telerik grid custom field not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, telerik

I'm trying to fill a column of the my grid with images from the Content/images folder of the project, but for some reason the column doesn't display any content.

Since maybe I wrote the path in a wrong way, I tried to follow an example of the web with only some text, without any luck.

This is my custom column:

```
columns.Template(@<text>
   custom content here, which is not related to the data
   </text>).Title("Column Title");
```

I'm using Ajax binding, and because of that columns.ClienteTemplate is not an option (I need to use aggregates, which is not possible when Server binding.

This is my data source (abreviatted):

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
          .Ajax()
          .Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Home"))
          )
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering how it's done, here is the answer:

```
    columns.Template(@<text>custom content</text>)
      .ClientTemplate("<img src=" + "../Images/LogoSGM-small.png" + " />")
      .Title("IMG");
```